# How to infer arguments based on the argument that was provided to the first function?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a utility function that will take a single `value` from an `enum` and will infer the returned function arguments based on an `interface` with a `type` field that matches the `value`.

I'm struggling how to map `value` and find the interface with a field `type` that matches the `value`

```
enum ActionTypes {
  One = 'One',
  Two = 'Two',
  Three = 'Three'
}

interface Action1 {
  type: ActionTypes.One
}

interface Action2 {
  type: ActionTypes.Two
  meta: {
    fieldName: '2'
  }
}

interface Action3 {
  type: ActionTypes.Three
  payload: number[]
  meta: {
    fieldName: '3'
  }
}

type AllActions =
  | Action1
  | Action2
  | Action3

const createAction = <T>(type: T) => (
  payload?: //infer payload from AllActions.type === T,
  meta?: //infer meta from AllActions.type === T,
  ) => ({
  type,
  ...payload && { payload },
  ...meta && { meta }
})

const action1 = createAction(ActionTypes.One)
action1()

const action2 = createAction(ActionTypes.Two)
action2(undefined, {
  meta: {
    fieldName: '2'
  }
})

const action3 = createAction(ActionTypes.Three)
action3([1, 2, 3], {
  meta: {
    fieldName: '3'
  }
})
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=55&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQBUCeAHYBnKAbwCgooB5EYKAXigHJLh6AaUqdAdxVoa5Vbt0ACwBOwanXojxzYgF9ixJCATBRAMwCGcavGRoAjEXYIcwAFyxEqDObwA6JgqUq1mnXptoATCbJmuFb6tli4jvzsEMAIWlYkZGQaSMAANgAmAHJa0Vb0PvTsiorKqurautYGIADM-lCBllWh9g4yEuzYWpipKFrpVuAQAEbqANoAulExcfVJKRnZuQw1hWTFSo2wqakhaAQ07AA+zUbHpyA+53u1SnD7CFBw4lpqN7wAPOgAfAAUjVZ0ABKWjfKC-TrdXr9AD8VgA9PCVBp1FAuj0+ukoBpRChoDAdjdHFsaKSOGwyNFYnCoIjkaiqVpsbj8YTvCBieZaGT0BSoCCaGDfgkGuY+Q4JejoViAGQyohoqGYqDycUSxlQOUKjXFIF3B5QHTVYx0Z7AV7AG6-G5hfBOKh6o22Qy-PXEe4cx5O3y8M0Wq021r8R3sny-MAgdLAZJUdIseqM+LseZpLI5Jr5NYqhRuj14L3suqml5vdnW9m2iJiCQh6o1X5jQzxnzxmoTeMixNzbELNPLeirIo5oA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type the function, but there are several things we need to consider:

1. `T` should extends `AllActions['type']` in order to capture the literal type of the value passed in.
2. To extract the action associated with `type: T` we need to use the predefined conditional type `Extract<AllActions, { type: T }>`
3. Since according to `T` the inner function can have a variable number of parameters, we will need to use [tuple in rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) in order to spread a variable number of parameters into the resulting function.
4. Using tuples in rest parameter with manually declared tuples will result in the loss of parameter names, so instead of building a tuple like `[P, M]` and spreading it out, we will instead build a function signature, extract the parameters as a tuple, and spread that tuple back to a rest parameter ( `function fn(...a: Parameters<(x: number) => void>) {}` will have a single number parameter named `x`, while `function fn(...a:[number]) {}` will have a single number parameter named `a_0`, which is not ideal)
5. We can use a custom conditional type to build the desired signature based on the presence of `payload` and `meta`.
6. Since conditional types that contain unresolved type parameters are pretty bad when writing the implementation, we will use a separate implementation signature for the inner function.

Putting all these things together we get:

```
type Payload<T> = T extends { payload: infer P } ? P : undefined;
type Metadata<T> = T extends { meta: infer M } ? { meta: M } : undefined;
type CreateActionParameteres<A> =  /*4*/ Parameters<
  /*5*/ A extends { payload: infer P, meta: infer M } ? /*4*/ (payload: P, meta: { meta: M }) => void :
  /*5*/ A extends { payload: infer P } ? /*4*/ (payload: P) => void :
  /*5*/ A extends { meta: infer M } ? /*4*/ (payload: undefined, meta: { meta: M }) => void :
  () => void>

const createAction = <T extends AllActions['type'] /*1*/ >(type: T) =>
{
  function inner(...a: CreateActionParameteres</*2*/ Extract<AllActions, { type: T }>>): /*2*/ Extract<AllActions, { type: T }>
  function inner(payload?: Payload<AllActions>, meta?: Metadata<AllActions>) { /*6*/
    return {
      type,
      ...payload && { payload },
      ...meta && { meta }
    };
  }
  return inner;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=52&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQBUCeAHYBnKAbwCgooB5EYKAXigHJLh6AaUqdAdxVoa5Vbt0ACwBOwanXojxzYgF9ixJCATBRAMwCGcavGRoAjEXYIcwAFyxEqDObwA6JgqUq1mnXptoATCbJmuFb6tli4jvzsEMAIWlYkZGQaSMAANgAmAHJa0Vb0PvTsiorKqurautYGIADM-lCBllWh9g4yEuzYWpipKFrpVuAQAEbqANoAulExcfVJKRnZuQw1hWTFSo2wqakhaAQ07AA+zUbHpyA+53u1SsRbAArdvf0APOgAfLzoUMAAHmoQOkCIQoF0en0BlAVBp1FAHlB5FAAPzwqBWMBA4DJKjpADc93MUAAsjN0lpYu8vnQfv9AcCiFBorErDC4cTESjGczZhykRisTjgPjCbgoABhcQU4A3J6iHIxdT4V4walkOUK9x4V7sGC-AGgBmg8EvKFs0TwlhMmaskCwi18rkAChNkKsDytPPi1pZJMRAEpaF8AG4oJDpdG6-X0kFg55u6F2uEIpGol3x-ruwM0ENhiMWKN0w2xr2J+1+1NQdMQzNQTHpbEqYWem3c1t87O58ORshOztQUPhj7sYhwfYIKBwKVqG68d7R4vbXbeEB4Mb0Rr0CYfJ2NKzoTvEBJQDSYleJqiiJ0OG+zSXAaWyrTy5lK7UAUQB8sQKp2NzwVqgnuHCIh8Hz+lYn4IN+CC-su1QAYywE-PIw5JGe1QXuo1amsi7oZukcH-h8LaxHhJJkhSWhESueDgXMUDiAgYCiCADEBOYbCJIkN4OK6-RQAAZIJjL8RG8hcdxUC8TyQkiaCsmKNx8gEus7BMSxbEqJeBIlGOq4Tjo1TGHQU4PjOK5OjcYT4E4VD+sQRm2IYfZKPpeCGSufimdOMqWdZrT8A5Tm+E69aNrigHTL6x7zGkWQKnkBRFAoDmjuOUAhbUvBmY+-krjZERiBIwUrjUTpjIYVo+FaNQTFFZClrFJ4LAlyz0KsKXyGlQA)